# Transaction handling in Node MySQL pooled connection

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have promisified my `mysql` connection so that I can use promise chaining in my sql connection.

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 50,
    host: keys.connection.host,
    multipleStatements: true,
    user: keys.connection.user,
    password: keys.connection.password,
    database: keys.connection.database,
    dateStrings: true 
    // debug:true                //Set this to true for verbose debugging. Leaving this to default for now cause it is creating too many messages at my console
})
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            console.error('Database connection was closed.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
            console.error('Database has too many connections.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            console.error('Database connection was refused.')
        }
    }
    if (connection) connection.release()
    return
})

pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query)
```

I wanted to create some tables in my database and I want none of the query to be executed if one of the query fails

```
async function UpdateSchema_1_0_1() {
    try {

        await pool.query(`CREATE TABLE \`printer\`(
                        \`ID\` int(10) NOT NULL,
                        \`Station\` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                        \`Printer\` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                        \`XML\` varchar(6000) NOT NULL,
                        PRIMARY KEY (ID)
                    )`)

        await pool.query(`CREATE TABLE \`printerqueue\`(
            \`PrinterID\` int(10) NOT NULL,
            \`OrderNumber\` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
            FOREIGN KEY (PrinterID) REFERENCES printer(ID)
            );`)

        await pool.query(`Alter table users add column printerID int(10) Default 1;`)

        await pool.query(`ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT fk_users_printer FOREIGN KEY (printerID) REFERENCES printer(ID);`)

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

Is there a way to to use commit and rollback transaction in my promisified mysql pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to rollback CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statements anyway. This has nothing to do with connection pools or Node.js. In MySQL, each DDL (Data Definition Language) statement causes an implicit commit.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html for details.

So there is no way to do a bunch of DDL statements as one atomic group (all succeed or else rollback the work done so far). At least not using the feature of atomic transactions.

If one of your DDL statements fails, and you want to "roll back" to return the database to the state it was before you started the group of DDL statements, then you'll have to reverse any prior DDL statements manually.

Of course, some types of DDL changes can't be reversed except by restoring the database from backup, because the changes destroy data. Like DROP TABLE or ALTER TABLE... DROP COLUMN. To reverse these changes and restore the data that was in that table or column, you'd have to have the original data.